# How can I scale a value when it is within a threshold?

Tags: special-functions

> I am not a mathematician so I'm not even sure of the correct language
>   to describe this. I also don't know what appropriate tags are for this
>   question so please amend as necessary.

I am looking for a function that would scale it's input when it is within a threshold of a value. The closer the input is to the value, the more dramatic the scaling would be.

For example, given a function `x(y, t, s)` where `y` is the input ranging from `0.0` to `1.0` and `t` is the threshold and `s` is a scale factor, I require the following output:

```
x(0, 0.9, 2)   = 0  
x(0.1, 0.9, 2) = 0.1  
x(0.2, 0.9, 2) = 0.2  
...  
x(0.8, 0.9, 2) = 0.8  
x(0.9, 0.9, 2) = 0.9 
x(0.95, 0.9, 2) = 1 
x(1.0, 0.9, 2) = 2 // maximum effect when input is 1.0
x(1.05, 0.9, 2) = 1 // effect slopes off as input > 1.0
```

The behaviour I'm after is such that when input is less than threshold, the output is equal to the input e.g. `x(y, t, s) = y` where `y <= t`, and the output should be `s` when the input is `1.0` e.g `x(1.0, t, s) == 1.0 * s` when `t < 1.0`.

So

`x(y, t, s) = y` where `0 <= y <= t` and
`x(1, t, s) = s` where `t < 1.0`

Note, this is just an example of the behaviour I'm looking for, if there are any well known mathematical functions that produce a similar effect I'd be happy to accept those as suggestions.

Comment: The problem is unclear, could you rephrase it in text? Is your function $x$ independent of $s$ or what happens if you vary $s$? Do you mean that $x(y,t,s) = y$ if $0\leq y\leq t$? Do you mean $x(y,t,s)= 1$ if $t<y<1$ and  $x(1,t,s)= s$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AD, I've updated the question. Let me know if this is any clearer.